# Trying to rotate a 2D array 90 degrees clockwise, but it is going counter-clockwise

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Rotate
{
public static int[][] rotateArray(int[][] orig)
{
    int[][] neo = new int[orig.length][orig[0].length];
    for(int r = 0; r < orig.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < orig[0].length; c++)
        {
            neo[(orig.length - 1) - c][r] = orig[r][c];
        }
    }
    return neo;
}
}
```

This question has been answered before, but because I am new to programming and all I know is Java, I was unable to follow the best example I found because it was in C#.  Sorry for the duplicate.
I named the new rotated array neo because I wanted original and new, but then remembered new can't be used to name variable so I used neo which means new :)

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is c# or java, algorithm is not language specific. If you already have solution on C#, you can follow along their algorithm.

Comment: this is not true : `int[][] neo = new int[orig.length][orig[0].length];`

Comment: it's better to be like : `int[][] neo = new int[orig[0].length][orig.length];`

Comment: Could it be that your 2D array is not indexed as Row,Column but rather as X,Y ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple modification of your code sample. Notice how the rotated array dimensions and the rotation algebra are changed.

```
static int[][] rotateArrayCW(int[][] orig) {
    final int rows = orig.length;
    final int cols = orig[ 0 ].length;

    final int[][] neo = new int[ cols ][ rows ];

    for ( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        for ( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            neo[ c ][ rows - 1 - r ] = orig[ r ][ c ];
        }
    }

    return neo;
}
```